# Awesome Window Manager: Force firefox to initialy open on a specific screen (3 head)

Tags: multiple-monitors, awesome-wm

I have a 3 monitor setup using Awesome Window Manager.

I have a few applications I always start up when I log in, and I have to place them on the correct screens/tags manually.

Is there a way to do this programmatically? Something in rc.lua? I would like to be able to move them to other screens, and have other instances of the same applications not forced. In other words, this is just a initial setup force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start up applications automatically at login, you could add them to your `~/.xinitrc` or so. Here is an example.

```
gtk-redshift &
calised &
urxvtd -q -o -f &
```

To have them opened on a specific tags / screen , see the *awful rules* : https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ#How_to_start_clients_on_specific_tags_and_others_as_floating.3F, specifically this example :

```
 -- Set Xterm to multiple tags on screen 1
 { rule = { class = "XTerm" }, callback = function(c) c:tags({tags[1][5], tags[1][6]}) end},
```